# Why will the following simple grand central dispatch program not work correctly?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

So I was expecting the following program to print two lines. However it doesn't print anything. Any ideas on what needs to be fixed?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <dispatch/dispatch.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
 printf("Done outer async\n");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
         printf("Done inner sync");
    });
 });

 return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to call `dispatch_main()` if your program does not have an event loop:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
        printf("Done outer async\n");
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            printf("Done inner sync");
        });
    });

    dispatch_main();
    return 0;
}
```

From the documentation:

> This function "parks" the main thread and waits for blocks to be
>   submitted to the main queue. Applications that call `UIApplicationMain`
>   (iOS), `NSApplicationMain` (Mac OS X), or `CFRunLoopRun` on the main
>   thread must not call `dispatch_main`.

Comment: Thanks. However, with dispatch_main() it just hangs after printing the "outer sync" message. I was expecting it to execute the "inner sync" message too.

Comment: @healthdev: It does if I run that program. - Perhaps print a newline  or add `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: I'm running on the command-line with clang gcd.m -o gcd -framework Foundation

Comment: @MartinR `fflush` doesn't fix it, but it's indeed an issue with `printf`.

Comment: Ok, I forgot to add newline in the second line. So it wasn't flushing the buffer. Now it works. Also works with NSLog. Thanks Martin and Gabriele

Comment: Forget what I said. Either `fflush` or a newline after the inner `printf` will cause the output buffer to be emptied and both logs to be printed.

Answer (score 2):

Your main thread ends first, shutting down the rest when you return 0 -- this is why nothing is printed since your other dispatches don't get a chance to be executed.